# Process data from return by an ajax request, but outside the callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback, getjson

I have this code.

```
/*
   Get the source of the data.
*/

if (if_the_source_is_an_url) {

  $.getJSON(url_here, function(returnedData){ theData = returnedData; });

}

/*
   Here we have the default processing of theData.
*/
```

So i need that if the user provides an url, the retured data will be processed but outside of the callback function, becouse i need to reuse the data processing code. So, i came with this ideas.

- Use the break command
  `$.getJSON(url_here,
  function(returnedData){ theData =
  returnedData; break;});`
- Change to an $.ajax request but with
  async: false
- just put the data processing inside a
  function and call it from the
  callback function.

  `if (url) $.getJSON(url_here,
  function(returnedData){
  customFunction(returnedData); });
  else customFunction(defaultData);`

Any ideas if this will work (i did not tested it becouse im not at home), or are there better practices for this?

Comment: I think thrid option(call the data processing function from callback) is the best way to proceed.

Comment: I will take your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Attach handlers/functions using [jQuery.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to filter/transform/etc your data.  The handles your attach here will be called for all of your ajax requests